# How to change text color which I search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a searching service. If I type `"v"` in the input box, I get a list from ajax and show it.

I want to change the color of the matching portion. If the list item is `"solve"`, the `"v"` would be red.

```
$('input[name="searchInput"]').on("propertychange change keyup paste input", function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  if (currentVal == oldVal) {
    return;
  }
  oldVal = currentVal;

  callHtml('@Url.Action("SearchInput", "Search")', {
    search: currentVal
  }, function(data) {
    if (data) {
      $("#searchResult").html(data);
    }
  })
})
```

I've tried this code under `$("#searchResult").html(data);`

```
$(".searchlist").replaceAll(currentVal, "<span>" + currentVal + "</span>");
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I suggest to not reinvent the wheel and use a ready to use third-party tool like http://easyautocomplete.com/

Comment: Can you share a small snippet of what `data` might look like?

Comment: data is partial view. which contains ul>li

Comment: and each li contains <a> data text <a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the HTML structure you mentioned in your comments, you could use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) with [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to target `<a>` elements in which `currentVal` is found.

I'd then use `.split()` and `.join()` to wrap the matches in a `<span>` (you could alternatively use a regex `replace`, but it gets tricky with some reserved character matching).

```
$("#searchResult")
  .html(data)
  .find(`a:contains(${currentVal})`)
  .html((idx,old) => old
    .split(currentVal)
    .join(`<span class="highlighted">${currentVal}</span>`)
  );
```

---

```js
var oldVal;
$('input[name="searchInput"]').on("propertychange change keyup paste input", function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  if (currentVal == oldVal) {
    return;
  }
  oldVal = currentVal;

  //mock data
  var data = `<ul>
                <li><a>hello</a></li>
                <li><a>world</a></li>
                <li><a>hello world</a></li>
                <li><a>foobar</a></li>
                <li><a>boo</a></li>
                <li><a>far</a></li>
              </ul>`;

  $("#searchResult")
    .html(data)
    .find(`a:contains(${currentVal})`)
    .html((idx,old) => old
      .split(currentVal)
      .join(`<span class="highlighted">${currentVal}</span>`)
    );
    
});
```

```css
span.highlighted {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="searchInput" placeholder="Search text">

<div id="searchResult"></div>
```

<sup>(Keep in mind that this example isn't conditionally hiding/showing matching results, just demonstrating the highlighting)</sup>